# What is the difference between a " line " and a " straight line "?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, definition

Is there actually a difference between a line and a straight line ?

Is figure 1 a line . ?
[image: -]
.

Should I take help from " Euclid "?
I believe according to " Euclid " the above figure is a valid line.

Comment: I think what you draw is indeed a line, a curved line to be exact.  However, it is conventional to say that a "line" refers to a straight line.  If you have a curved line, then the convention is to use the word "curve."  However, maybe other geometers can confirm or refute what I say.

Comment: May be of interest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve

Answer (score 0):

According to Euclid, "A line is breadthless length" *(Elements I, Definition 2, T. Heath translation*). So your figure appears to be a line. Euclid says a *straight* line is "a line which lies evenly with the points on itself" (Def. 4). The exact meaning of this definition has been disputed, but it seems clear at least that, for Euclid, a line and a straight line are not the same thing.